# JavaScript function: The counter should count up incrementally every second and the counter should stop once it reaches the given number

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to write JavaScript function where the counter should count up incrementally every second and the counter should stop once it reaches the given number in the input field after onClick() . And also I want to Highlight box1 when the counter is divisible by 3. Highlight Box2 when the counter is divisible by 5.

JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  var number = parseInt($('#test').text(), 10) || 0; // Get the number from paragraph
  // Called the function in each second
  var interval = setInterval(function () {
      $('#test').text(number++); // Update the value in paragraph

      if (number > 5) {
          clearInterval(interval); // If exceeded 100, clear interval
      }
  }, 1000); // Run for each second
});
```

HTML:

```
<form>
  Enter the Number <br>
  <input type="number" placeholder="Number" value="input" id="text">
  <button type="button" value="Submit" id="tmsec"></button>
  <p id="test"></p>
</form>

<div>
<div class="box">
  <p>Finger</p>
</div>
<div class="box">
  <p>Toes</p>
</div>
</div>
<button type="button"> Reset </button>
<button type="button"> Restart </button>
```

Comment: The document ready function counts up to 5 successfully, but what have you tried that responds to mouse clicks?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do following:

```
var MAX = 999;

$(document).ready(function () {
  var number = parseInt($('#test').text(), 10) || 0;
  var interval = setInterval(function () {
      number++;

      var max = $('#text').val() || MAX;
      $('#box1').css('background-color', number % 3 === 0 ? 'red' : '');
      $('#box2').css('background-color', number % 5 === 0 ? 'red' : '');
      $('#test').text(number);

      if (number >= max) {
          clearInterval(interval);
      }
  }, 1000);

  $('#test').text(number);
});
```

I also added ids to boxes:

```
<div class="box" id="box1">
  <p>Finger</p>
</div>
<div class="box" id="box2">
  <p>Toes</p>
</div>
```